# how to filter specified content from textview?

Tags: android, filter

i am beginner in Android

i have list of news that i got by implementing rss feed and shown in first activity.when clicked on particular news it will navigate to particular news detail activity. In in second news detail activity[see the picture 2.png and 3.png] the blue colored text is news title.

The problem is how to filter and remove all the red and blue underlined text from detail activity[see the picture].

The code with source code is appreciated.thanks

[news list activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaXTw.png)

[news detail activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDNDT.png)

[news detail activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRGmk.png)

Comment: Does the title of the news has fix position ? at the end of news ?

Comment: yes... it is showing by default from rss feed

Comment: i want to remove all the blue and red underlined text.

Comment: i searched that it can be done by implementing filter method but dont know how to solve

Answer (score 1):

If you have title always in last line. you should remove that line. by doing this.

```
String final_news = news_which_has_title.replaceAll("<ul>.*</ul>", "");
```

now you can set `final_news` in textview in `new detail activity`

Comment: the blue underlined text only is title and i want to remove text from red including blue underlined till the end.

Comment: I think you should post that string.